# Backlight keyboard commands working on live CD but not on installed ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, backlight

so basically when i put the ubuntu installation disc of Ubuntu 11.10 inside and run a Live session everything works fine (i can press Fn + Arrow Up and Fn + Arrow Down to control the screen Backlight).

But after that i install the system, it doesnt work anymore... but other commands (like Fn + Arrow Left for lowering the volume) are working

i've installed latest nvidia propretary drivers (and maybe thats the issue?), coz i dunno what other drivers i could use

waiting an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And then find the Section "Device" and add the bold line.

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Default Device"
Option "NoLogo" "True"
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```